# docker websocket attach using unix sockets

Tags: node.js, sockets, docker

I have docker running on `/var/run/docker.sock`.

I want to attach to a container. So I hacked the `ws` library to get it to send both socketPath and path in it's request. Basically, it sees `ws+unix:///var/run/docker.sock:/containers/theid/attach/ws?args` and does the right thing. The problem is: docker returns a 403 forbidden on the request. Is websocket access through a unix socket just disabled?
If I make the same request to `http://localhost:3000/containers/theid/attach/ws?args` the websocket connection works fine (I have the docker daemon listening on both http and unix socket).

Also, looking at the docker daemon logs, I see the expected GET request

Thanks!

Comment: As you haven't linked to your code can you also give the output of running the docker daemon with debugging `docker -d -D `

The API setup is done in `api.go`
 https://github.com/dotcloud/docker/blob/master/api.go#L1013
 https://github.com/dotcloud/docker/blob/master/api.go#L778

Comment: @JaredForsyth hi jared, can you share your tcp socket connection? I'm having 403 forbidden request error on regular tcp socket http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23119145/docker-websocket-attaching-in-nodejs?stw=2

Comment: Shouldn't it be possible to just expose a port on the container? There's a [docker/websocket walkthrough](http://www.giacomovacca.com/2015/01/dockerize-nodejs-websocket-server-in-5.html) that looks really promising, but I'm still getting connection refused at this point. :/

Answer (score 0):

The internally used websocket library currently verifies requests to contain an `Origin` header with a valid URL:

```
func checkOrigin(config *Config, req *http.Request) (err error) {
    config.Origin, err = Origin(config, req)
    if err == nil && config.Origin == nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("null origin")
    }
    return err
}
```

(snippet from: https://github.com/golang/net/blob/master/websocket/server.go#L102).

If the header is invalid or missing, you'll get a status 403 response though the Docker logs don't show any errors.

A simple solution is to add a valid header to your initial request looking like this:

`Origin: http://localhost`